# how can i terminate ec2 instances using ansible dynamic inventory?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-playbook

i have searched the whole  internet and cannot find anwser to this question. "how can i terminate an ec2 instance using dynamic inventory with tags?" 
so if i can terminate an instance or group of ec2 instances with specific tag(s)

the ec2 module requires one to pass the instance-id but there is nothing automated in doing that. SO looking for a way to target specific tags using dynamic inventory with ansible

```
- name: terminate single instance
   hosts: all
   tasks:
     - action: ec2_facts
     - name: terminating single instance
       local_action:
         module: ec2
         state: 'absent'
         region: us-east-1
         instance_ids: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
```

I have tried the above with the following comamnd

```
ansible-playbook terminate.yml --tags "tag_Name_web_server"
```

which means i want too delete ec2 instances with `Name' tag 'web-server`
Right now when i run that, it looks through several ec2 instances but it to only target those with the specified tags. Short story, does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem as you

As of today (Ansible 2.5 to be precise), it is possible to do what you want without host_vars with the [`ec2_instance` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_module.html?highlight=ec2) (it's different from the `ec2` module)

For example, you want to terminate all ec2 instances with the tag-value pair: `Usage:k8s-ansible`, this is the task you'll need:

```
ec2_instance:
  state: absent
  filters:
    tag:Usage: k8s-ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

`--tags` switch has nothing common with ec2 tags:

> -t TAGS, --tags=TAGS  only run plays and tasks tagged with these values

You should use external variables and host pattern:

```
- name: Terminate tagged instances
  hosts: tag_{{ tag_name }}_{{ tag_value }}
  tasks:
    - ec2_facts:
    - ec2:
        state: absent
        region: "{{ ansible_ec2_placement_region }}"
        instance_ids: "{{ ansible_ec2_instance_id }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

execution: `ansible-playbook -e tag_name=Name -e tag_value=web_server terminate.yml`